# Why is concatenation called when using dynamic obj + class obj?

Tags: c#, dynamic, null, concatenation

I have such an example code:

```
static void Main()
{
    dynamic dynamicObject = null;
    object simpleObject = dynamicObject + new AnyClass();
    Console.WriteLine(simpleObject);
}

class AnyClass
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "text";
    }
}
```

Execution result is:

```
text
```

If I understood it correctly, then part `dynamicObject + new AnyClass()` calls the string concatenation, which return empty string for `dynamicObject` due to it refers to `null`, and `new AnyClass()` returns `text`. But there's no string argument, which is necessary to call `ToString()`. Why does it happens so? Why is an exception not being generated about the lack of implementation of the operation '+'?

Comment: _"there's no string argument, which is necessary to call ToString()"_ - what string argument?

Comment: @Fildor I assume they mean that there is nothing obvious to force the object to execute ToString. Like "hello " + new AnyClass().

Comment: @SMSTJ That's why I am asking. So we don't have to assume :D

Comment: @Fildor I know when type of at least one argument of '+' operation is a 'string' then invokes ToString() for the second argument, but here no arguments of string type and in spite of it, ToString() called for each

Comment: "But there's no string argument, which is necessary to call ToString()"? Every object has ToString().

Comment: yes, but my question is why ToString() called here at all?

Comment: Interesting thing is that it will even do this if you just do: null + new AnyClass();

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/7D17Z2, yep. Seems more of a thing about `null` than `dynamic`.

Comment: My best guess is when you have null as one of the operands the String.Concat() will be called. From lang specification the implementation of this method considers null as empty string. If you declare a null object and try to print the sum of this object with another object you got a compiler error. If in the same expression to add + null, the code will compile and you the result that will be the concatenation of ToString() of the other operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a matter of [operator overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1245-binary-operator-overload-resolution). Since neither `null` nor `AnyClass` declare any user-defined operators, the [built-in overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12105-addition-operator) of `+` are considered. Here is a non-exhaustive list.

```
string operator +(string x, string y);
string operator +(string x, object y);
string operator +(object x, string y);
decimal operator +(decimal x, decimal y);
int operator +(int x, int y);
long operator +(long x, long y);
float operator +(float x, float y);
double operator +(double x, double y);
```

Since the second parameter is an instance of `AnyClass`, everything that doesn't take an `AnyClass` as a second parameter is eliminated, and we are left with:

```
string operator +(string x, object y);
```

Therefore, this is the operator that is called.

Of course, the results would be different if you declared your own `+` operators.

Comment: So, in my view this would make the code in question really brittle, won't it? Having the dynamic var always null doesn't make sense, so I think it's safe to assume there will be cases where it's not. Which in turn means, that a different overload that _does not do the same as this one_ could (or even will) be chosen ... right?

Comment: @Fildor Yeah, IMO that's the nature of dynamic-typed code.

Comment: Now that I read it, yeah that makes sense. Brittle by design.

Comment: All of the value-type operators are lifted, so `null` does not in fact exclude any of the value type operands.  `AnyClass` not being convertible to any of them is what excludes them.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. I forgot about lifted operators.